# Google spreadsheet custom function input values

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, custom-function

I was recently working on a project for student grades.
I'm very inexperienced so i ran into problem pretty quickly.

```
function MyFunction(A,B,C) {

if (A < 4.5); {
return "failure1"}

if (B < 4.5); {
return "failure2"}

if (C < 4.5); {
return "failure3"}
}
```

I had some other stuff aswell, because this is obviously not complete but for some reason these commands do not seem to work.

I always get failure1 even though the cell to which I assign A is higher than 4.5

For example I type in a cell `=MyFunction(A2:C2)` , and the output is just failure1 even though my A2 contains a value higher than 4.5 .

Comment: Hi, I noticed a typo here:
if (A < 4.5); — redundant semicolons. They are everywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax errors

- Semicolons indicate end of statement
- A complete if statement requires a condition and statement.
- `{`,`}` enclose blocks.

Another problem is that the function, implies that the arguments are simple values, not objects, so you should not use a range as input.

An alternative way to write your funcion is the following:

```
function MyFunction(A,B,C) {
  if (A < 4.5) return "failure1";
  if (B < 4.5) return "failure2";
  if (C < 4.5) return "failure3";
}
```

The way to use it is the following:

```
=MyFunction(A2,B2,C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a range as argument to a custom function it gets a bit tricky. In your function this will be an array of arrays making it a bit of a challenge to work with.

So when you call `=MyFunction(A2:C2)`, your custom function gets this:

`[[a, b, c]]`

where a is the value in cell A2, b from cell B2 and c from cell C2.

Here's a sample of how you might work with something like that (say to sum the values in the range):

```
function myFunction(values) {
  var x = 0;
  values.forEach(function(values) {
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      x += value;
    });
  });
  return x;
}
```

The trick is dealing with the fact that you have an array within another array, so I need to iterate over the outside array, and then iterate over the inside array accumulating each of the values to get the sum.

Working with single inputs is much easier and works a little closer to what you might expect.